# Apply a linear gradient to a spline with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to do this linear gradient ([image spline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWLv.jpg)) of a spline.

[image]

When the value is good the spline will have to be green, but if the value is not good the spline will have to be blue.
The picture corresponds more or less to my case.

This is my test

```
series: [{
    data: [60000, 40000, 30000],
    color: {
      linearGradient: [0, 60000, 0, 30000], 
      stops: [
        [0, '#7CB5EC'],
        [1, '#00FFA8']
      ]
    }
  }]
```

I would like the bigger value to be blue and the smallest value of green. Why do not I see any shade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention axis for gradient like

```
linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 }
```

see here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
    data: [60000, 40000, 30000, 80000],
    color: {
    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
    stops: [
        [0, 'blue'],
        [1, 'green']
    ]
    }
  }]
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ponmudi/w7433n2d/

Comment: You're right, I was confused with other examples. thank you so much!